# Distribute Android Apps Privately via Email List

Tags: android

Is there an easy way to privately distribute android apps? The users of the apps are not employees and I will only have their email addresses. Further the apps cannot be from "unknown sources" - I can't just email the apk.

When I looked into how to "Manage private apps in google play" the target audience seems to be enterprises where the enterprise would actually manage the devices of their employees.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

It looks like it would be easy enough to create the app and assign it to an organization, but to actually manage users in the organization, the articles I have read talked about needing an enterprise mobility management (EMM) provider.

https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6396012

I am aware of closed testing as being one option to do something like this.

Is there an obvious way to distribute the apps that I'm missing?

Edit: The users of the apps are customers (not employees or testers)

Comment: If not EMM or Google Play, I'm not sure if you can avoid the "unknown sources" enable issue, but if the issue is about handling multiple apps, you could create your own store (see open source F-droid) but that would require your own server/hosting.

Comment: Is there like a simple EMM provider that will let me manage a list of users?

Answer (score 0):

How about [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution)?

You only need email addresses and you can send apks or app bundle files.

Really easy and straightforward, I use it, and the Spark plan is free.

Comment: FIrebase looks good, but it appears to be a testing solution. My concern is that my end users are customers so they might get confused if I give them a "test" version of the app.